# "Sign on" or "sign onto"?

Tags: grammar

how can I describe the physical act of signing:

> *Signing me **on** the official register of...*

or

> *Signing me **onto** the official register of...*

It is a ceremony and the register contains many other signatures. Thanks!

I was trying to describe a picture of me signing an important thing and I came out with this doubt.

Comment: If you want to give this information: a) me b) signing c) register, you can skip the preposition entirely and say "(Me,) signing the official register of...". Basically what you already wrote in your question. If you want to say something more complicated, see @MARamezani 's comment.

Comment: Based on your last sentence, I'd say you can simply say: **Signing my name in the official register at (place name).**

Comment: Thank you for these suggestions. I will use "Signing the official register of..."

Comment: And don't forget "sign on to":  Signing me on to the official register.

Comment: 'Signing on' has connotations of 'joining or becoming part of something' like a club, or the military, or unemployment benefit. I wouldn't use it for 'putting your name on the marriage register' for instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use plain *sign*.

> I signed the book.

*Sign on* means something different - it means to register availability somehow, to be available over a communications medium, or the equivalent to *logging in*, i.e. *sign on to that account*.

If you say

> I signed on to the official register of ...

it makes me think you just logged into a website.

Now, *sign on with* or *signed on for* might be interpreted as *registered with*, *subscribed to*, or *joined by signing up for*, but usually would be *sign up with* or *sign up for*.

> I signed on with the official register of ... (Sounds OK)
>
> I signed up with the official register of ... (Sounds better)

But none of those mean physically, actually signing something.